# Iterate through Table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

What is the best way to iterate through the contents of each cell in a table and retrieve/store its value.
With my current approach, I'm unable to obtain set the value of a table in my variable `val`

Sample Table:

[image]

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Name = "sheet1"

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("tblBor")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ws.Calculate

With tbl.Sort
         .SortFields.Clear
         .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("tblBor[ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
         .Header = xlYes
         .Apply
End With

Set rng = Range(tbl)
rows = tbl.Range.rows.Count
Columns = tbl.Range.Columns.Count

For iter = 1 To rows
    For col = 1 To Columns
        'Iterate through each row by each column
        'val = tbl.DataBodyRange(iter, col).Value

    Next col
Next iter
```

Comment: [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) is a built-in function. Maybe use a different name. Also you have a typo `Columns = tbl.Rable.Columns.Count`, what's `Rable`? Finally, you need to be consistent - you're using both `tbl.Range` and `tbl.DataBodyRange`. `tbl.Range` includes the header row. Not sure you want that. You might also want to consider a different name for `rows` and `Columns`.

Comment: changing the variable names did the trick. Also, would it make more sense to iterate through each column or is it more advisable to use `tbl.ListRows(iter).Range(1, col).Value`

Comment: I think the current approach is cleaner. `tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(iter, col)`.

Comment: @BigBen the problem with `Range.Cells(row, col)` is that it's retrieving objects in an object collection *by index*, which is inefficient. Object collections *want* to be iterated with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree. I would have proposed an array approach as you actually did :) (guess I'm just too lazy today to write out an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `ListObject`, use its API! `ListRows` and `ListColumns` are object collections, and the fastest way to iterate these, [by several orders of magnitude](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/), is with a `For Each` loop:

```
Dim tblRow As ListRow
For Each tblRow In tbl.ListRows
    Dim tblCol As ListColumn
    For Each tblCol In tbl.ListColumns
        Debug.Print "(" & tblRow.Index & "," & tblCol.Index & "): " & tblRow.Range(tblCol.Index).Value
    Next
Next
```

If you just want to collect the contents into a 2D array of values, you don't need to iterate anything - just grab the `DataBodyRange` and treat it like any other "regular" `Range`:

```
Dim contents As Variant
contents = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value
```

If you later need to iterate that 2D variant array, the fastest way (same source as above) is `For...Next` loops:

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = LBound(contents, 1) To UBound(contents, 1)
    Dim currentCol As Long
    For currentCol = LBound(contents, 2) To UBound(contents, 2)
        Debug.Print "(" & currentRow & "," & currentCol & "): " & contents(currentRow, currentCol)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: any reason you put the `Dim currentCol` inside the first For loop?

Comment: @chrisneilsen because I like my variables declared as close as possible to where they're used. `Dim` statements aren't executable though, so it pragmatically doesn't make a difference; `Dim currentRow As Long, currentCol As Long` above the outer loop would be just as good, but I don't like declaring multiple variables in a single instruction, so...

Comment: Thanks for that.  _so it pragmatically doesn't make a difference_. That's why I asked, unless one is aware of that, it might be misleading. (I've answered a Q where the OP was expecting  a Dim to execute on each iteration )

Comment: @chrisneilsen TBH in real code I'd probably extract the inner loop into its own procedure; having the variable inside the outer loop body makes it easier to just cut that code and paste it in a new method... where it would now be declared just above the loop body ;-)